# How can several user controls respond to an event that occurs in one of them in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, checkbox, user-controls

I have a user control that consists of a checkbox. I have 4 of these user controls on a form. When the user clicks any one of the checkboxes in the user control, I want the other user controls to ensure they are not checked. Similar to the way that radio buttons would work, except I need to use checkboxes and events.

Comment: Why do you need to use checkboxes instead of radio buttons?

Comment: @zespri - You cannot unselect a radio button once it is selected (accidentally). Something user might not want to select any option.

Comment: This is usually solved by adding 5th radio-button "none of the above"

Comment: The checkboxes are only standing in for something else. Im working on a number of user controls that will act like paint tools in a paint program. I want to show a visual indication that a user has selected one of the tools and I want to have the app unselect any other selected tool at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way could be use a single method for all the events of the `CheckBox`es and exploit the `sender` object in this way:

```
List<CheckBox> listCheckBoxes;
```

---

```
checkBox1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkBox_CheckedChanged);
checkBox2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkBox_CheckedChanged);
checkBox3.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkBox_CheckedChanged);
checkBox4.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkBox_CheckedChanged);

listCheckBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ToList();
```

---

```
void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    if(checkBox.Checked){
        foreach(CheckBox c in listCheckBoxes){
            if(c.Checked && c != checkBox)
               c.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The event handler is typically a method of the form (or a custom container).  You typically know about other controls at that level.  If you're trying to execute that event handler on the custom control itself you're going to have issues because you'll be tying the control to other controls.

It would be a better design to have some sort of container control that has an event handler to perform this logic.  That event handler would then be added to the `Click` event of each of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap up the controls in a single `UserControl`.  When an event fires on a single `CheckBox` control raise a general toggle event for the remaining `CheckBox` controls.

Answer (score 0):

OK , if i am assuming right . you got 4 usercontrols in a form and they need to communicate with each other on some event ( in your case it is event caused by checkbox in one of your user control)

I would implement subscriber /publisher model.
In Usercontrol-A (publisher)
 1) On checkbox click raise a event , forward this to a common event function

Page class which contains the usercontrol , will subscribe to the event of UsercontrolA and if required forward it to Usercontrol B (subscriber)

for more details see this
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15550/How-to-invoke-events-across-User-Controls-in-ASP-N